# Unix find and move command

Tags: unix

I need a Unix command to find all the text files older than 3 days and move them to some other location in single command.

Comment: Do you want a directory tree in the "other location" that reflects the original structure, or do you want to move all the files to the top level of a single directory? In the latter case, what if `dir1/foo.txt` and `dir2/foo.txt` are both more than 3 days old? And in either case, what if you move `dir1/foo.txt` today, then recreate it tomorrow and move it again 3 days later? In short, how do you want to handle duplicate file names?

Comment: Before attempting to do anything like this, please read [the "Security Considerations" section of the GNU `find` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Security-Considerations.html#Security-Considerations) *very carefully*.  If you screw this up, a malicious person with write access to the source directory for the files to be moved will be able to trick `find` into moving critical system files out of position.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you want find and use its -exec and -mtime flags.

Comment: Give it a try yourself first.

Comment: find . -name *.txt -mtime +3 -type f | xargs -i mv {} /other location

Comment: I'd do find . -name *.txt -mtime +3 -type f -exec mv \{\} /other/location \;

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
find . -mtime -3 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I file mv file /new/dir/.
```

[man find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

[man xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)

Comment: You don't need xargs, since find can run a command on what it matches with -exec

Comment: I know that I don't need xargs, but I prefer it.

Comment: The OP most probably wants -mtime, not -ctime.

Comment: Oh dear. Bet you I can break your system if you do that.

Comment: @wildplasser, you are probably correct, but the OP asked for "older than 3 days" not "not changed in 3 days".